# Relativistic composite system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, kinematics

Say, two particles, $m_1$ and $m_2$, each have rest mass $M_1$. Each particle has total energy $E$ in the centre of mass system. What is the mass of the composite system consisting of the two particles as viewed from a frame of reference in which $m_1$ is stationary?

I'm thinking about finding an expression for the energy of the moving particle ($m_2$) and using $E=mc^2$ to find it's mass, then add $M_1$ to it.  However, it seems very complicated and this question only provides 2 minutes. Can anyone give any hints to some other more simplistic methods to solve this problem?

Comment: Hint: mass—properly defined—is a Lorentz invariant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remember that in the center of mass system $\vec p_{tot} =  0$, therefore you can write the two four-momenta for the two particle as $p^{\mu}_1 = (E, \vec p)$ and $p^{\mu}_2 = (E, -\vec p)$ whence $(p_1+p_2)^\mu = (2E, 0, 0, 0)$.

Then remember how it is define the total mass of a system i.e. if we have N particles with different four-momenta, we can write 
$$M^2_{tot} = (p_1^\mu + p_2^\mu + \dots + p_N^\mu)^2=(p_1^\mu + p_2^\mu + \dots + p_N^\mu)(p_{1\mu} + p_{2\mu} + \dots + p_{N\mu}) = 
(p_1 + p_2 + \dots + p_N)^\mu(p_1+p_2 + \dots + p_N)_\mu$$
(these are just different way of writing the same thing). This mass is a Lorentz invariant therefore...(i leave to you  the conclusion)